# React Router v4 nested routes not work with webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4

I try to setup nested routes for my react app like this

- `/` -> Home Page
- `/about` -> About Page
- `/protected` -> protected default page
- `/protected/page1` -> protected page 1

It works fine in codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nested-route-utqy7) React 16.8.1 React Router 4.3.1

But when I set the same thing up with webpack-dev-server (3.7.1), it can only reach `/` and can't reach to the rest routes.

My file structure is like

```
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.jsx
│   └── index.html
├── webpack
│   ├── paths.js
│   ├── webpack.common.js
│   └── webpack.dev.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

paths.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  outputPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'build'),
  entryPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'src/index.jsx'),
  templatePath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'src/index.html'),
};
```

webpack.common.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const convert = require('koa-connect');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const commonPaths = require('./paths');

module.exports = {
  entry: commonPaths.entryPath,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      },
    ],
  },
  serve: {
    add: app => {
      app.use(convert(history()));
    },
    content: commonPaths.entryPath,
    dev: {
      publicPath: commonPaths.outputPath,
    },
    open: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: commonPaths.templatePath,
    }),
    new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
      defaultAttribute: 'async',
    }),
  ],
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const commonPaths = require('./paths');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: commonPaths.outputPath,
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: commonPaths.outputPath,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack/webpack.common');

const devConfig = require(`./webpack/webpack.dev.js`);
module.exports = webpackMerge(common, devConfig);
```

index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Homepage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  </div>
);
const AboutPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>About</h1>
  </div>
);
const Protected = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Protected default page</h1>
  </div>
);
const ProtectedPage1 = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>ProtectedPage1</h1>
  </div>
);

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={Homepage} exact />
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />

      <Route
        path="/protected"
        render={({ match: { url } }) => (
          <div>
            <Route path={`${url}/`} component={Protected} exact />
            <Route path={`${url}/page1`} component={ProtectedPage1} />
          </div>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I think some paths are incorrect in my config, I just can't figure out where is wrong.

Answer (score 45):

I finally figured out the reason that webpack-dev-server couldn't serve nested routes.

As a single page application, when you visit `/somepath` of your react app, it actually fallback to the `/` and pass the pathname to react router. React router will navigate you to `/somepath` by the using browser's history API.

webpack-dev-server, for some unknown reason, doesn't enable this "fallback to history API" behaviour by default.

So, we need to add `historyApiFallback: true,` to the `devServer` of webpack config.

Now, all top level routes, like `/somepath` should work, but for nested routes, like `/somepath/morepath`, it's not enough.

With default webpack-dev-server setting, the compiled html template will point to the bundled js like `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>`. Pay attention to the `src="main.js"` which assumes the `main.js` is under the same path as the `index.html`. The assumption is true for top level path `/somepath` but for nested routes, `/somepath/morepath`, this assumption will lead html file to access `main.js` like `/somepath/main.js`.

So, we end up with looking for a way to specify a certain place for html file when it's going to access the bundled js. And, it's the job of `publicPath`. Adding `publicPath: '/',` to the output block of webpack config. It will tell html to always access `main.js` from `/` folder and the compiled html will be `<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>`. That's exactly what we're looking for.

Comment: yeah this is the answer ```    output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      publicPath: '/',
    },```

Answer (score 19):

Try adding:

`<base href="/" />`

to the `<head>` tag of your `index.html`. This way it'll always look for `/main.js` bundle, even for nested routes.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem described in the question (webpack-dev-server not serving nested routes, top level ones working fine). Sadly, neither `historyApiFallback: true` nor `publicPath: '/'` were working. Actually, the problem was inside `index.html`, more precisely inside `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`. Changing to

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>       <!-- do include slash before the file name -->
```

was enough to end the pain.

Comment: This is what really helped me. Changing `publicPath` to `'/'` has absolutely no effect, neither in `devServer.publicPath` nor in `output.publicPath` also the webpack documentation says that it is a default value anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To summarized the answer by @Bing Lu, in your webpack.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = () => ({
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ...,
  ...,
  output: {
    ...
    publicPath: '/' // <- this is the important line along with historyApiFallback = true in the dev server config
  },
  ...,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    ...
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

basically wrap, your react app using `<HashRouter>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>` working fine without any webpack config modification, if you don't want to use HashRouter then you can free to use historyApiFallback: true in web pack dev server config on bottom of webpack.config file

```
like so
 const config = {

........
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
        https: false,
        historyApiFallback:true
    }
}
```